# Difference between partially ordered, totally ordered, and well ordered sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory, well-orders

I just started studying set theory and I'm a bit confused with some of these relation properties.

Given a set ***A*** = {8,4,2}, and a relation of order ***R*** such that a***R***b means "a is a multiple of b", we would have the following relations:

{8***R***8, 8***R**4, 8***R**2, 4***R**4, 4***R**2, 2***R***2}

(I think a correct notation for this set of relations would be ***A/R*** but frankly I'm not too sure so if anybody could confirm or deny that, it'd be appreciated)

If my understanding of relations is correct (which it might very well not be), the relation would be reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric, therefore we would have a partial relation of order.

Now, since in this partial order all elements are related to each other, it would be a total order relation.

And since all non empty subsets of the set A would have a least element, it's a well ordered set

If, however,  instead of ***A*** = {8,4,2}, we had ***A*** = {8,4,2,3}, we would just have a relation of partial order since 3 wouldn't be related to any of the other elements in the set.

On another note, in order to have a well-ordered set, we first need a totally ordered set, right?

<s>Also lastly, if ***A*** started out at $2^n$ where $n = \infty$ and $n$ descended until 1, the set would be totally ordered but not well ordered,  right? I'm aware this notation might be terrible but I don't know how to get the idea across otherwise so yeah. Any help and advice with notation and general understanding is also appreciated</s>

Edit: A correction on this last paragraph: after reading some of the replies and re-reading my own message I've noticed how what I've written makes basically no sense, so I'm going to re-do the question:

The set I was (very poorly) trying to describe was ***A*** = { $2^n  |  n \in \Bbb N $ } only backwards for some reason. So reading the replies, they say it's a totally ordered set but not a well ordered set. Seeing as $2^n  |  n \in \Bbb N $ has a least element (if $n = 0$), I was wondering why it wouldn't be a well ordered set.
In other words, do all of the subsets of any set with a least element also have a least element?

Comment: The notation $A/R$ is usually reserved for the case where $R$ is an *equivalence* relation on $A$, in which case $A/R$ is the set of equivalence classes of $A$ under the relation $R$.

Comment: "Partial relation of order" is confusing (it clashes with notions like "partial functions"). What you have is a relation of "partial order".

Comment: Also, $R$ is a relation. $1R2$ is not a relation, and we don't talk about the set of $R$ as relations, plural.

Comment: What you want is to either write $R=\{(8,8), (8,4), (8,2)$ etc. , or to say that we have the relations $8R8$, $8R4$, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Can I ask: are you familiar with the definition of a relation on $X$ being a subset of $X\times X$? (I only ask because there are other ways to define relations, and sometimes what a relation actually "is" is kept informal anyway.)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh yeah, whenever I read the notation on the book I guess I just kind of "generalized" from equivalence classes and now I kind of apply the concept of "classes" where it probably shouldn't be.

I'm going to use the fact that I use the terms in spanish as my excuse to mix up words and say stuff with words out of order but yeah I'll be more careful next time and hopefully not get it wrong.

I appreciate the advice on notation. I'm really bad at it

Comment: As far as the edit is concerned, under the usual ordering $\{2^n\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$ is indeed well-ordered, but under your "is a multiple of" ordering it is not, since that ordering is reversed.

Comment: @Joe Yeah, that was the first definition of relation I read. And seeing my terrible notation to represent my "set of relations" I clearly didn't remember it. Oops, lesson learnt.
I'm confused about your second answer though. The set you wrote down is not well-ordered? I kind of explained where my confusion comes from in my edit. It just seems to me like 2 should be the least element of the set, but I might be missing something.

Comment: @MW Oh, I think I get it. I had this idea that the order of the elements of a set doesn't matter but I guess it does while establishing relations, kind of how A x B isn't the same as B x A? Also I don't think I ever mentioned that  {8,4,2,3} was a well-ordered set. I never changed that paragraph, I only meant to say it was a relation of partial order.
I did edit the paragraph after that one, but I meant to do that edit right after posting since I kind of re-read some things from both definitions and the post itself and noticed that I knew the answer to what I wrote so it shouldn't be there

Comment: @badatmath: Let's look at the definitions. Assuming that $A=\{2^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is equipped with the relation $R$, where $aRb$ means "$a$ is a multiple of $b$", then this is a partial order, since it satisfies reflexivity, antisymmetry, and transitivity. A least element of $A$ would be a number $l\in A$ such that $lRa$ for all $a\in A$; that is, it would be a number $l\in A$ such that $l$ is a multiple of $a$ for every $a\in A$. Evidently, $2$ is not a multiple of every element of $A$.

Comment: By the way, I think is a fairly confusing example, and so I don't blame you for struggling with it, as I had to check a few things myself. The reason it is confusing is that we are much more used to studying the relation "$a$ divides $b$".

Comment: @Joe Wow. Thanks. That was extremely helpful

Comment: @badatmath: I don't find the last paragraph of your (updated) question completely intelligible, but I think there is a sensible idea that you are groping towards. There is some discussion of orders in Halmos' book *Naive Set Theory* that you might find useful. Take your time and I'm sure you will understand it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb07V.jpg. Halmos uses $\le$ to denote an arbitrary partial order, and $\omega$ to denote the set of natural numbers $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Addendum: consider, say, the set $(0,1)\cup\{-23\}$ under the usual ordering of real numbers. This set is totally-ordered, but not well-ordered. Even though $-23$ is the least element, the subset $(0,1)$ does not have a least element.

Comment: "Relación de orden parcial" no es lo mismo que "relación parcial de orden". ¡En español, el orden también importa!

Comment: @badatmath actually you are correct, while you did originally talk about the set being well-ordered, it looks like you fixed your question just minutes before I posted my answer.  My apologies for implying otherwise, I have deleted that comment.  Regarding your the question about the order of elements in a set mattering, the order you *write* the elements in does not matter at all.  Only the ordering relation that you define is relevant.  $\{2,4,8,3\}$ and $\{8,3,2,4\}$ are exactly the same set.

Answer (score 0):

The source of confusion you might have comes from the sort of casual way that we often talk about "partially ordered sets".  A set itself, strictly speaking, is an un-ordered entity.  Two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements.  So $\{1,2,3\}=\{3,2,1\}$, etc.

When we speak of a partially ordered set, what we are really referring to is a pair $(S,R)$, where $S$ is a set and $R\subseteq S\times S$ is a relation that satisfies the axioms of a partial ordering.  We sometimes will say "$S$ is a partially ordered set under the relation $R$", but that's really what could arguably be called casual abuse of terminology, since $S$ itself is just an arbitrary set.  When we say something like this, we're communicating that whenever we talk about $S$ as being ordered, we are referring to the partial ordering defined by $R$.

In your final edited question, you ask if $A=\{2^n  |  n \in \Bbb N\}$ is well-ordered.  This is a fine question to ask provided that you've already clarified what ordering relation $R$ you are talking about.

If $R$ is the usual ordering for integers (restricted to $A\times A$), then the answer is "Yes, $A$ is well-ordered".

If, on the other hand, $R$ is the relation you described in the beginning of your post, i.e., $aRb$ means $a$ is a multiple of $b$, then under this relation, $A$ is not well-ordered, since the ordering is reversed from the usual ordering - every subset will have a greatest element, but not necessarily a least one.  In particular, $A$ itself does not have a least element under this ordering, as $2^0$ is the greatest element, then $2^1$ precedes $2^0$ as  $2^1R2^0$, likewise $2^2$ precedes $2^1$ since $2^2R2^1$, etc.

The answer to your final question was given by Joe in the comments, but let me just re-emphasize it here, that no, just having a least element for a set does not imply every subset has a least element.  The real interval $[0,1]$ under the usual ordering has a least element, but the subset $(0,1)$ does not have a least element, so $[0,1]$, though totally ordered, is not well-ordered.